# Can you lose your mined XMR from a pool?

Tags: mining-pools, wallet-recovery, balance, wallet, unlocked-balance

In the past I had generated a wallet and used that address to mine in a pool (minexmr). I had mined for a couple of months and I remember that I gather a "substantial" amount. However, I never received a payment since I didn't reach the threshold.

I stopped mining, and today (after 1~2 year) I decided to restore my wallet from the seed and see what's going on. Restoring from the seed  gave me a wallet address, that I guess it's the same as the old one?

Subsequently, I went back to the pool and entered my address to check what I had mined but there is nothing "credited" to my wallet. Is this normal? Have I lost what I had mined in the past as I never reached the threshold and never got paid?

Did I do anything wrong with restoring my wallet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It clearly says this in the Terms and conditions page.
"Accounts which are inactive for longer than 365 days may be deleted. Any remaining balance will be treated as a donation to the Pool."
https://minexmr.com/terms

So yes you can loose your mined coins by being inactive for long.